# Slider revolution video autoplay device

Tags: wordpress, video, slider, landscape, revolution-slider

I'm trying to put a html `video` in the revolution slider. For Mobile devices don't autoplay so I added a play button.

But for the landscape of the Ipad, because of its size my Play Button isn't visible there (1024px is laptop size) and Laptop autoplays so I don't want to add a useless button there. 
So I wish to know what would be the best way to solve this?

I think that hidding the button whe it's a computer could be a good idea... but I'm not sure how to do that.

I though about making the button layout visible for laptop and adding this code

```
`@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) /*is that the right orientation for computer?*/
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
.tp-caption .tp-videoposter:after {display: none}
}`
```

Thanks for your help, 
Have a good day

Comment: please add some code to your question, People will be more inclined to answer

Comment: thanks for your comment, I did that :)